# object Object & undefined GET variables

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, pdo, get

Here's what I'm trying to get `response14.php?questionID=1&question=yes&approved=1`

Here's what I'm currently getting `response14.php?questionID=[object%20Object]&question=undefined&approved=1`

Here's the js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".save_btn").on('click', function() {
         var check = $("input[name=no]").is(":checked")?2:1;
         var questionID = $("textarea[id=questionID]").val();
         var question = $("textarea[value=question]").val();
        location = "response14.php?questionID=" +questionID + "&question=" +question + "&approved=" +check;
```

And here's the form:

```
echo "<script src='viewsonly.js' type='text/javascript'> </script><br><center>";    
    include("db_conn.php");

$qry_strings4 = "SELECT * FROM `Y new questions`";
$preps4 = $pdo_conn->prepare($qry_strings4);
            $preps4->execute();
           // $row = $preps4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //echo "$count";
            echo "<table style='border:0px; background-color:lightgrey; width:75%'><thead style='border:0px;'><tr style='border:0px solid white; background-color:#153E7E; text-align:left; color:white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><th style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Question</th><th style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Response</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
            while ($row = $preps4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<tr style='border:1px white; background-color:lightgrey; color:black; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><td style='border:1px white; vertical-align:top; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>{$row['starName']}</td>
                      <td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><div id='wrap'>
<textarea cols='85' rows='2' id='{$row['questionID']}' class='response textbox'>{$row['question']}</textarea>
YES: <input type='checkbox' name='yes[]' value='yes'>
NO: <input type='checkbox' name='no[]' value='no'>";
            }
            echo "</tbody></table>";
            echo "<button type='button' class='save_btn'>Save All</button><br>";
```

rendered html:

```
 <td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><div id='wrap'>
<textarea cols='85' rows='2' id='3792' class='response textbox'>Hello C!!

Where can I send you fan mail? :)
I want your autograph and I'm from the Philippines :)

God bless Cooper!</textarea>
    YES: <input type='checkbox' name='yes' value='yes'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    NO: <input type='checkbox' name='no' value='no'>    </div></td></tr><tr style='border:1px white; background-color:lightgrey; color:black; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><td style='border:1px white; vertical-align:top; padding: 5; margin: 5;'>Gavin Casalegno</td>
                      <td style='border:1px white; padding: 5; margin: 5;'><div id='wrap'>
<textarea cols='85' rows='2' id='3793' class='response textbox'>What is your religion?
Do you believe in God?
How much you measure height?</textarea>
    YES: <input type='checkbox' name='yes' value='yes'> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    NO: <input type='checkbox' name='no' value='no'>    </div></td></tr></tbody></table><button type='button' class='save_btn' style='align:right'>Save All</button><br>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this???

I have just added the rendered html as requested

Comment: `$("textarea[value=question]")` seemes strange. Also php code looks unrelated to question.

Comment: I was trying to edit the var check one for the others and the php code shows the textarea and checkbox

Comment: I think PHP is related, but only because it shows how the form is created.  The HTML would be more useful for it though.  Related to the question though: `"textarea[id=questionID]"` and I don't believe you have a `textarea` with `id=questionID`, rather I believe it's number based.

Comment: added the rendered html above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a unique element with id `questionID`, in this assignment you should add quotes around the attribute:

```
var questionID = $("textarea[id='questionID']").val();
```

even you may simply write

```
var questionID = $("#questionID").val();
```

---

Here you're targeting a textarea by a value attribute,

```
var question = $("textarea[value=question]").val();
```

but textareas don't provide a value attribute (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) for further information)

---

Finally, if you want to perform a `POST` request you need to use ajax. (since you're using jQuery see the documentation of `$.post` method)

Comment: now it says `questionID=undefined&question=undefined` and yes questionID is unique

Comment: wouldn't this `var questionID = $("#questionID").val();` show the value in the textarea?

Comment: are you sure you have really those elements in page? Could you look at the source code that your browser is receiving?

Comment: both `var questionID = $("textarea[id='questionID']").val();` and `var questionID = $("#questionID").val();` are still showing undefined. see rendered html above to see source code

Comment: what the output in console of `console.log($("#questionID"))` ?

Comment: where does this go `console.log($("#questionID"))`

Comment: you may write it in you browser console.

Answer (score 1):

To use post method, you can do like this:

First wrap your table with form element with `action="response14.php"`,
then use submit button to submit your form with validation as required.

Or

You can use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax).